# Harry Potter fanfic where he never got his Hogwarts letter and lives on his own in an apartment

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Harry didn’t live with the Dursleys. He lives by himself in an apartment with a snake.

The Order was trying to find Harry and ended up chasing him multiple times although they found it difficult to catch him. Sirius was out of Azkaban so it’s after third year.

I’m pretty sure at some point in the beginning the Order found Harry at a club with a guy and Sirius being impressed (I think). Harry eventually agrees to go to Hogwarts but everything after that is blurry.

I mainly read on AO3 and fanfiction.net so it’s probably on one of those sites.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)